# python-escpos windows giving "bugtrack_url" error

Tags: python-3.x, escpos

Trying to install python-escpos library. The instructions say the following:

Ensure the library is installed on `${lib_arch}/${python_ver}/site-packages/escpos`

On CLi you must run:

```
python setup.py build
sudo python setup.py install
```

What does `${lib_arch}/${python_ver}/` mean? Is it the path such as
`\Users\RickT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\escpos`?

When I run `python setup.py` build, I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\RickT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\distutils\dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url' warnings.warn(msg)Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 140, in <module> 'python-escpos = escpos.cli:main'
```

Comment: The bugtrack_url-issue is just a warning, because setuptools doesn't know that token. Which documentation are you referring to? Could you please give an URL?

Comment: Moreover, do you really need to build the package? Installing with pip should also work on Windows.

Comment: Hi @Ricky T has my answer helped you? If yes, would you please consider marking it as a solution?

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in the comments you should write which version of the documentation you are using and which version of the codebase you are using.

The "error" considering the `bugtrack_url` is just a warning because setuptools does not know this token. This should not affect your setup in any way. You probably installed it successfully.

Concerning your question about the path: `${lib_arch}/${python_ver}/site-packages/escpos` is more or less non-sense in a Windows-context. This just means your location of the `site-packages`-directory. So, your assumption is right.

All in all the probably easiest solution for you would be installing with pip. This would simply be - considering you have a working pip - a one-liner:

```
pip install python-escpos
```